# Merging two generic lists

Tags: c#, linq, list, generics

Created a class

```
 public class DBClass: IDisposable
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Score { get; set; }
    }
```

Used this class to create list of the class.

```
        List<DBClass> dbc1 = new List<DBClass>();
        List<DBClass> dbc2 = new List<DBClass>();
```

I have added two different set of data to the list.
note : *This is just an example*

```
        dbc1.Add(SetDBClass("A", 100));
        dbc1.Add(SetDBClass("B", 100));
        dbc1.Add(SetDBClass("C", 100));

        dbc2.Add(SetDBClass("B", 200));
        dbc2.Add(SetDBClass("C", 200));
        dbc2.Add(SetDBClass("D", 200));
```

I need a `List<DBClass>` object with the above two objects merged but in the below fashion.

*A - 100
B - 300
C - 300
D - 200*

**How can the above be achieved by LINQ or any-other way ?**

If you want to exclude the same data from both list then do as follows :

```
ParentDB.Where(b => !((from x in mainDataSource select x.Name).Contains(b.Name))).ToList();
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
from x in dbc1.Concat(dbc2)
group x by x.Name into g
select new DBClass(g.Key, g.Sum(x => x.Score))
```

Comment: This worked. But DBClass doesnot have any constructor. I changed a couple of part. Work like charm thanks :)